# javax.inject.Qualifier Spring JavaConfig

Tags: annotations, jsr330

I have the following code

The 2 `javax.Inject` Qualifiers

```
@Qualifier
@Target(value={ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Hibernate {
--nothing goes here
}


@Qualifier
@Target(value={ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Toplink{
--nothing goes here
}
```

---

I Qualify the repositories

```
@Named
@Hibernate
public class HibernateRepository implements IRepository{
-- some code
}

@Named
@Toplink
public class ToplinkRepository implements IRepository{
-- some code
}
```

---

These repositories are injected using `javax.Inject`

```
public class InvoiceService {
    @Inject
    //@Hibernate  I alternate between the two to test
    @Toplink
    private IRepository iRepository;
    public void saveInvoice(Invoice invoice){
    iRepository.save(invoice);
}
```

---

using the following configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class Myconfig {

    @Bean
    public IRepository getHibernateRepository(){
        return new HibernateRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public InvoiceService getInvoiceService(){
        return new InvoiceService();
    }

       @Bean
        public IRepository getToplinkRepository(){
        return new ToplinkRepository();
    }

}
```

**This code works perfectly fine when I use the XML configuration , any idea how to get it working with javaConfig ?? Or is there something fundamentally wrong in my code ?? When used its throws the following exception**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'getInvoiceService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.domain.IRepository
>   com.service.InvoiceService.iRepository; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type [com.domain.IRepository] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(),
>   @com.domain.Toplink()}

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of @Bean methods, it's the return type that counts.  Even though you may be returning a TopLinkRepository from one method, and a HibernateRepository from another, from the container's point of view, all it knows is that there are two beans of type IRepository, and therefore does not understand that one is @Toplink annotated and one is @Hibernate annotated.

You have several of choices here.  The simplest, given your current configuration, would be to change the return types to make them more specific.

The second is to leave the return types generic, but move the @Toplink and @Hibernate qualifier annotations to the @Bean method level.

The third is to component-scan for the repository types instead of declaring them as @Bean methods.

The third approach is generally recommended, given that you're already using @Inject on the repository components, and have them marked with @Named.  This makes them natural candidates for component-scanning in the first place.  Check out the Javadoc for @ComponentScan to see how to do this in the @Configuration class world.

Comment: are you sure Spring (3.1) supports _javax.inject.Qualifier_ in `@Bean` methods? I'm currently struggling with the same problem because I want to instantiate generic repositories programmatically and "`@Inject @MyQualifier`" doesn't work when the bean was created using "`@Bean @MyQualifier`" in a `@Configuration` class.